# How to update latest changes in Database to appear on Recyclerview on remove/add immediately?

Tags: android, sqlite

How can I make the changes that happends in the database like delete/add to immediately be shown in the recyclerView too? I have tried notifyDataSetChanged(); and deleted from the arraylist directly too and reloaded the database list again. But all this seems like a messy work-around code and dosn't work?

Here is a video of a delete action in my app which shows how it is right now.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCJnunOWBR4

**This is the activity that starts when the user clicks on an event from the recyclerview:**

```
 public class EventActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.event_activity);

    loadDatabaseData(this);
    rvAdapter = new RvAdapter(databaseList, this);


    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    toolbar.showOverflowMenu();
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra("TITLE"));

    pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("POS",0);


}

 //Delete or remove happends here:---------------------
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_saveToDb:
            DbHelper.getInstance(EventActivity.this).saveToDb(eventID, title, description, subtitle, start, end, 1, url, imgURL);
            loadDatabaseData(getApplicationContext());

            break;

        case R.id.delete_from_Db:

            DbHelper.getInstance(EventActivity.this).deleteEvent(eventID);

            //these 3 lines dosn't help either
            loadDatabaseData(this);
            rvAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(pos);
            rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            finish();

            break;

        default:
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



public void loadDatabaseData(Context context) {

    databaseList = new ArrayList<>();

    dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
    sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DbHelper.DATABASE_NAME, null);
    EventCurserWrapper wrapper = new EventCurserWrapper(c);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            databaseList.add(new Event(wrapper.getEvent().getEventID(),wrapper.getEvent().getTitle(), wrapper.getEvent().subtitle, wrapper.getEvent().getDescrption(), wrapper.getEvent().startTime, wrapper.getEvent().endTime, wrapper.getEvent().url,wrapper.getEvent().getImgURL(), wrapper.getEvent().isDb));
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }

    wrapper.close();
    c.close();
}
```

}

**This is the MainActivity that has the recyclerView:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
public RvAdapter rvAdapter;
private List<Event> databaseList, allEventsList, jsonList;
private DbHelper dbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private SharedPreferences preferences;

private static final String URL = "http://events.makeable.dk/api/getEvents";
private static final String DESCRIPTION = "description_english";
private static final String TITLE = "title_english";
private static final String SUBTITLE = "subtitle_english";
private static final String PICTURE_URL = "picture_name";
private static final String EVENT_ID = "eventid";
private static final String DATES = "datelist";
private static final String EVENT_URL = "url";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int showListPref = preferences.getInt("SHOW_LIST", 3);

    databaseList = new ArrayList<>();
    jsonList = new ArrayList<>();


    loadDatabaseData(this);
    new JsonParser().execute();


    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    toolbar.showOverflowMenu();
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Events in Arhus");


public void loadDatabaseData(Context context) {

    dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
    sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DbHelper.DATABASE_NAME, null);
    EventCurserWrapper wrapper = new EventCurserWrapper(c);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            databaseList.add(new Event(wrapper.getEvent().getEventID(),wrapper.getEvent().getTitle(), wrapper.getEvent().subtitle, wrapper.getEvent().getDescrption(), wrapper.getEvent().startTime, wrapper.getEvent().endTime, wrapper.getEvent().url,wrapper.getEvent().getImgURL(), wrapper.getEvent().isDb));
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }

    wrapper.close();
    c.close();
    sqLiteDatabase.close();

}



public void initRecyclerView(List<Event> list) {

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    rvAdapter = new RvAdapter(list, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
    rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's not good way resolving of problem. You can call `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()`.
And return some result from **EventActivity** to **MainActivity**, and if needed reload you data in RecyclerView.
You can read more about [Getting a Result from an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)